# Database.GetDbConnection() loses connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

The following code works.

However If I remove the code to set the connection string then it will fail the **second** time it is run with the error

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
> ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
> Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

```cs
public static List<T> RawSqlQueryOfT<T>(
    string query,
    MyDbContext db,
    Func<DbDataReader, T> map,
    params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    var entities = new List<T>();
    using var cn = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var cnState = cn.State;
    if(cn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
    {
        // if(cn.ConnectionString.Length == 0)
        //{
        //     cn.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();  // needed the second time
        //}
        cn.Open();
    }
    using var command = cn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    foreach(var param in parameters)
        command.Parameters.Add(param);
    using var result = command.ExecuteReader( );
    while(result.Read())
    {
        var r = map(result);
        entities.Add(r);
    }
    if(cnState == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
    return entities;
}
```

I am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0

The work around is to restore the connection string as shown in the commented out code.

[Update]

```
using
```

in front of the cn declaration causes the connection to dispose.

Comment: As written your code makes little sense. You don't open the connnection, but then at the end you do close it. Either open and close it yourself, or let EF take care of this (I don't know under which conditions it returns an open or a closed connection), but not a mix. Note that the `using` already takes care of closing the connection, so neither `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` nor your check for the `ConnectionState` (which erroneously guards a `.Close` when the connection is already closed) are necessary or useful.

Comment: It's also not clear what this method is supposed to achieve over something like, say, Dapper (assuming `DbContext.SqlQuery` can't already fulfill your needs). Writing your own logic for serializing things from a reader is a lot of work for little gain, and is especially pointless if you're sidestepping your existing ORM anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I use the map because it gives more control.  I will check Dapper out.

Comment: As you noticed, the culprit was disposing a connection you don't create. Note `GetDbConnection()`, not `CreateDbConnection()`.  Shortly, the code should not dispose the connection object. The code should be structured differently with `try/catch` to open the connection if needed, and leave it in the same state as it was before your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `MyDbContext db` as a parameter to the RawSqlQueryOfT creation.

My guess is that you've already given the ConnectionString to the `db` before it is used in this code. That's why it doesn't need initialization at first run.

Check also where framework reads that connection string implicitly before the `db` object is given here.

Later when connection is closed and related objects disposed also connection string is lost. From your code you can easily see that the `ConnectionString` property is part of a connection object.

Connection is closed because you are using `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` and double checking same thing by calling `cn.Close();` few rows later.

At second time you are creating a new connection to the database and should also supply connection string to the new connection.

See [MS documentation for `CreateCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand).

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection.  However it makes no difference.

Comment: cn.Close() only executes if the connection was originally closed. This leaves the connection as the method found it.